# gssapi requires Ruby version >= 1.9.1. on gem install

Tags: ruby, gem

I'm trying to install `knife-cloudstack` plugin using gem install on Ubuntu 12.04 with chef-client configured and got error as said in title.

```
>gem install knife-cloudstack
ERROR: Error installing knife-cloudstack:
       gssapi requires Ruby version >= 1.9.1
```

So i tried installing `apt-get install ruby1.9.3`, but still the same error.

Also, the version of ruby is shown 1.9.3

> ruby --version
>       ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [i686-linux]

To get more confused, when i run `sudo update-alternatives --config ruby` , its showing output as:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative ruby (providing /usr/bin/ruby).

     Selection    Path                Priority   Status
   ------------------------------------------------------------
     0            /usr/bin/ruby1.8     50        auto mode
     1            /usr/bin/ruby1.8     50        manual mode
   * 2            /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1   10        manual mode

   Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

PS: Initially the * was on Selection:0, i changed it later to 2.

Now where is ruby1.9.3? Even if i installed ruby1.9.3, why its taking other version?Anyone knowing what's causing the issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Removed ruby 1.8 from my system by that was the only one I had.

```
sudo apt-get purge ruby
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.3
```

then

```
gem install knife-cloudstack #(knife-vcloud for me)
```

worked for me.